# PDO prepared statement and bindValues from an array

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following block of code in a PDO statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO first_page_data (title, first_name, surname, phone, email, add1, add2, add3, add4, add5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['first_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $_POST['surname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(4, $_POST['phone'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(5, $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(6, $_POST['add1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(7, $_POST['add2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(8, $_POST['add3'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(9, $_POST['add4'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(10, $_POST['add5'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$_SESSION['buyer_email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

Can these parameters (title, first_name, etc) be put into the `bindValues` using an array and a `for each` loop? I can get the prepare statement working by just having an array containing the titles but cant seem to get the variable names inside the $_POST values. It would save quite a few lines of code, but I cant quite get there!

The following is the array im using in the prepared statement that I want to use in the bind value loop:

```
$first = array('title','first_name','surname','phone','email','add1','add2','add3','add4','add5');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply loop over `$first` and call `bindValue` for each one.

```
foreach($first as $key=>$val){
    $stmt->bindValue($key+1, $_POST[$val], PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Comment: Ok, turns out my idea of just putting $first in place of the list in the prepared statement doesnt work! it returns an array to string conversion - any ideas? Also, am i right to presume that as it isnt an associative array, the $key your mentioning is just the index (starting from 0, hence the +1) and the $val is the string from the array?

Comment: @Giovanni: What do you mean by "putting $first in place of the list in the prepared statement"?

Comment: @Giovanni: `$key` us the index of the array (it starts at 0).  `bindValue()` starts at 1, so that's why I used `+1`.  `$value` is the string from the array, so `$_POST[$val]` gets the value from the POST array.

Comment: I have "INSERT INTO first_page_data (***long list of parameters***), but I would like to replace the list with just the name of the array containing the list. Just replacing the list with $first returns an error....

Comment: @Giovanni: `$sql = 'INSERT INTO first_page_data (' . implode(',',$first) . ') VALUES (' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($first), '?')) . ')';`.  You want to use `implode` to turn the array into a string.

Comment: Implode, you little beauty!! Thanks alot!!

Comment: just deciphered the second half of the code in your comment; the `array_fill` line is another function id never used but wish id known about earlier!

Comment: @Giovanni: Glad I could help :-)  Yeah, the `implode(',', array_fill(0, count($first), '?'))` bit might look complicated, but all it does is return the right number of `?`s :-)

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use it like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO first_page_data (title, first_name, surname, phone, email, add1, add2, add3, add4, add5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->execute($array);
```

The array would be like:

```
$array = array($_POST['title'],$_POST['first_name']);
```

or if you have the correct order already just

```
  $array = $_POST;
```